# How to send stream from FFMPEG to a HTTP server?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, android-ffmpeg

I am making an Android app that creates a stream from a vulkan application, and also needs to host an http server.

I cannot rely on http servers like Nginx or Ngrok, which is where my issue lies.

Simple android-based HTTP servers (like nanohttpd) out there do not support the stream listening features that Nginx does.

How can I get a local m3u8 playlist (output by ffmpeg) over to a web server without relying on Nginx?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to output HLS from ffmpeg rather than a single video stream you could then more easily send to a server?

Comment: @Mick HLS is a requirement of the client receiver that'll actually play the stream

Comment: Ok, you do need the stream from the server to the client to be HLS in they case, but you don't need the leg from the phone to be HLS. The typical approach could be to use RTMP or RTSP etc from phone to server and then the server will convert to HLS.

Comment: Are there any off the shelf web servers on Android that can convert rtsp streams to HLS? We don't want our users to have to deal with setting up their own web server

Comment: You would need the clients to be able to access the phone but you can make a phone a web server - take a look here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-android-device-web-server/  Converting RTSP to HLS will be extra and I doubt you will find an off the shelf Android solution but you could create it yourself if you really need to go this way.